# STM32F412-Discovery + TouchGFX

Tags: stm32f4

Hi I've write a very simple, (although the demos appear to do the same) a TouchGFX project, one button two shapes..  seems to work perfectly in the simulator, just when i download using either the designer or the IDE, when I run i just get this screen[Screen on run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOyvd.jpg)  i'm assuming i've missed some configuration, but to be honest the designer tool, seems to do most of it...  I've tried two Discovery boards, both the same, and i've run the very simple Hello World project that could in the 1.27 FW pack..  and that works so i'm thinking the hardware is ok.  Could anyone give me any pointers please, I think i've just missed a step

Thank you

Andy

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuKDg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've written some basic GUI engine of my own for a disco, had almost every possible issue from QSPI through SDRAM, LTDC and DMA2D. This looks very much like external SDRAM issue. Maybe you don't initialize it correctly. You don't give nearly enough info to work with. Post hardware initialization code. Don't forget that SDRAM needs not only hardware configuration on MCU side, but also a few commands from MCU to be initialized and be ready for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an STM32412 DISCO board. It hits an assert initialising the touch driver.
The later version of the board has a different touch controller, see UM2032 D04 revision swaps the display to a FRD154B2902-D-CTQ, which changes the touch controller to an FT3267.
The TouchGFX project creator uses the BSP FT6x06 touch driver. ST do have an ft3x67 BSP driver (used on the STM32L4R9IEVAL board). If you bring that into the touchGFX project and modify the STM32TouchController.cpp file to use it, the